# TestNG Execution stops executing, when exception occurs, for NoSuchElement Found

Tags: exception

Running a TestNG testcase in Eclipse, and getting the values from Ui, using attribute("value").

BUt while execution, if the webelement is not present/Found on UI, I need  to take the UIvalue = 00:00.

```
    try {
        UIValue = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_AllowanceGridView_SRow"+cellRosterPerioddd+cellRosterPeriodmm+"_"+PayBucket)).getAttribute("value");
        // UIValue = WebelementforUIvalue;
    } 
    catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        UIValue ="00.00";
    }
```

But, When webelement is not Found, the execution stops, I do not want the execution to be stoppedm for the exceptions ?

Comment: Since you are catching NoSuchElementException that cannot be the reason the test stops. Are you sure the exception is not thrown elsewhere or it's not another exception that is thrown? Anyway, does not seem to be an ideal test if the element may or may not be there.

Comment: Please share the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

@Stijn

The execution runs, when the WebElements are found on UI, but it thorws 'No such Element' and stops execution, if the web element is not present on UI, in such cases, need to take the value as '00:00'

@ niharika_neo, Here is the Stack Trace below

### {code}

Excel PayBucket:JRM1
Excel PayBucket Value:03:40
UI PayBucket:[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (0a57a30b08559c4aa0fe4124c5950760)] -> id: ctl00_MainContent_AllowanceGridView_SRow2812_JRM1]
03:52

### Failed

Excel PayBucket:VOTPY
Excel PayBucket Value:02:01
UI PayBucket:[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (0a57a30b08559c4aa0fe4124c5950760)] -> id: ctl00_MainContent_AllowanceGridView_SRow2102_VOTPY]
03:52

### Failed

Excel PayBucket:VOTFA
Excel PayBucket Value:02:00
no such element
  (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 25 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'
System info: host: 'rainmaker2011-5', ip: '192.168.8.70', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0'
Session ID: 0a57a30b08559c4aa0fe4124c5950760
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\LAKSHM~1.PAL\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir14544_10752}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=39.0.2171.71, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
PASSED: IntegrationTests

{code}